# Heroku Bamboo to Cedar

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1, cedar

I have an existing Rails 3.1rc4 app deployed to heroku on the Bamboo stack. I would like to upgrate to 3.1rc5 and use the new Cedar stack. Since I can't use `heroku stack:migrate`, I have to create a new stack and push to that. The problem is that my current app is located at `appname.heroku.com`. If I simply delete this app, and recreate it using Cedar, then it would become `appname.herokuapp.com`. How would I move to Cedar while still keeping `appname.heroku.com`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy, just rename your old app to something like `appnameold` then create a new one with `heroku create appname --stack cedar`. Heroku takes care of the redirecting automatically and your previous links shouldn't break. You can [Google for `herokuapp.com` site names](http://www.google.com/search?q=herokuapp.com) and test them if you want to verify that.

If your question is how to have both subdomains separately or you simply like the look of `appname.heroku.com` over `appname.herokuapp.com`, however, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

I just did a migration to cedar stack today (by deleting the app via web interface and recreating it again with --stack cedar), and was glad to find out that the redirect is now automatic, from http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h16__redirect_to_herokuappcom:

> H16 - Redirect to herokuapp.com
>
> Apps on Cedar’s new HTTP routing stack use the herokuapp.com domain.
>   Requests made to a Cedar app at its deprecated heroku.com domain will
>   be redirected to the correct herokuapp.com address and this redirect
>   message will be inserted into the app’s logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't - Cedar apps use herokuapp.com - but you could put a sinatra app on appname.heroku.com to redirect to appname.herokuapp.com perhaps or within your existing app?? Or use a custom domain perhaps?

Comment: Redirecting to appname.herokuapp.com is not possible because I can't create a new Cedar app with the same name (It says name taken).